# Sencha Touch Ext.form.TextArea focus not opening keyboard

Tags: ios, sencha-touch

I am using Ext.form.TextArea of Sencha Touch 1.0 and using

```
focus()
```

to show the keyboard. 
But I dont get keyboard open every time, sometime keyboard appears and sometime it dont. I get the focus listener of TextArea getting called, but keyboard doesnot show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug registered under [`Sencha Touch 1.x Bugs`](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?121098-OPEN-725-Keyboard-has-not-appeared-on-focus-a-TextArea.)